# Create array with indexes of array based on value

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2D array like this:

```
map = [[0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2]]
```

I would like to get array of indexes based on values. For `example map[0][0] == 0` so I would like the pair (0, 0) to be on index 0 in the result array. The result array should look like this:

```
result[0] = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)]
result[1] = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
result[2] = [(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

I've struggled to get a result like this without writting a really bad code:

```
    val0 = []
    val1 = []
    val2 = []
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if(map[i][j] == 0) : val0.append((i, j))
            if(map[i][j] == 1) : val1.append((i, j))
            if(map[i][j] == 2) : val2.append((i, j))

    data = []
    data.append(val0)
    data.append(val1)
    data.append(val2)
```

Comment: Why don't you show us your code so we can get an idea of where you are?

Comment: I'd be you i'd do 2-dimensionnal for loops to take value from your `map` and append them to `result` where you want. But, as @FChm said, if you want us to help you, you'll need to show us some code.

Comment: After your edit : It seems you struggle with your actual "position" within the 2-dimensionnal loops. Check Droid's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the matrix and save where you see each value in a dict. That's your result.

```
retval = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(len(map)):
   for j in range(len(map[i])):
      val = map[i][j]
      retval[val].append((i,j))
print retval
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some `numpy` methods:

```
import numpy as np
map = [[0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2]]
npmap = np.array(map)
[list(zip(*np.where(npmap==x))) for x in range(np.max(npmap)+1)]
#[[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)], [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)], [(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]]
```